# How do i get the right path to cropperJS HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic2

I need to get the path right in order to make the crop feature work for application.I need to access cropper.js and cropper.css. This is what i have tried so far.Attached is the picture reference of the files that i would need to access.However the codes that i have tried is not working and returns an error.Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cannot GET /cropperjs/dist/cropper.js

And

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

```
 <link  href="/node_modules/cropperjs/dist/cropper.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="/node_modules/cropperjs/dist/cropper.js"></script>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you use webpack or other frontend compiler?

Comment: Do you mean the IDE i am using? i am using intelliJ Idea professional

Comment: I think i found webpack folder when i use inspect element at google chrome.I have edited the question accordingly

Comment: if it is webpack you should use include/require 'cropper' or how this package calls (look into  its package.json) from your code and webpack will makes necessary wrappers for this code. Do not forget to execute 'npm install' at first.